# How to make leaflet marker to appear after make a request such as search through search box which is an external div to my leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, search-engine, marker

I did make marker layer that contain some geojson information. What I actually want to do is to make a request of the marker. Assume that I have lots of marker, then every marker contains address and several other marker information(data). Then I assign them with an ID(even I still don't know how to assign it). Then I grouped all of them in a layer called marker layer and I wish to request one of the marker and I want the marker to show the address, coordinated and other info on exact point.  But, I do not know how to request individual marker from external search box of leaflet map. Could someone help on this? Should I just use val() or some other JS function?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What you describe does not sound to present any particular technical difficulty. It would be mainly plain JS objects manipulation (note that `val()` comes from jQuery for DOM manipulation), coupled with Leaflet `map.setView()` to move the view to a particular marker. Now the exact things you want sound a little bit vague. Please be more descriptive so that answers can be more detailed. Provide the code you already have, even if it is not working yet.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify the problem. I have make a div id="search" under div id="map" so that I will get a search box. I also have multiple markers in my map but I don't want it to appears at the particular location on the same time. So I wish to make a search functionality that can make the markers to appear on the map only when I request in the search box. It's like I control the info such as marker in the map from using search box that lies outside the map. I do make a research on L.Geosearch but it seems that the plugin does not meet my expectation. Hope you could help me

Comment: Maybe this plugin is more like what you want: [Leaflet Control Search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search)